# Click event added to a button that is in a web component works only once

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I have a class that contains three buttons that are used to navigate the app back and forth and so the content gets changed. However, the eventlisteners that I attempt to add to these three buttons on `connectedCallback` method, doesn't fired after it works once. When I click one of the buttons, f.e. next button, it does what expected: changes attribute of the other element but when I try to click and want to see a new screen, it doesn't work anymore. In inspector, I also looked for the events attached to the buttons, they stay there while buttons aren't work.

Is there anything that I miss. It's probably because of the shadow DOM but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

```
export class NavigationButtons extends HTMLElement {

constructor() {
super();
this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
this.render();

if (this.shadowRoot) {
    const styleSheet = document.createElement("style");

    styleSheet.textContent = styles;

    this.shadowRoot.append(
      navigationButtons.content.cloneNode(true),
      styleSheet
    );
  }
 }

 connectedCallback() {
const onrampModal = document.querySelector('pera-onramp-modal');

if (this.shadowRoot) {
    this.render();

    const step = onrampModal?.getAttribute('step');

    this.shadowRoot.getElementById("back-button")?.addEventListener("click", () => {
        onrampModal?.setAttribute("step", (Number(step) - 1).toString());
    }
    )

    this.shadowRoot.getElementById("next-button")?.addEventListener("click", () => {
        onrampModal?.setAttribute("step", (Number(step) + 1).toString());
    }
    )

    this.shadowRoot.getElementById("cancel-button")?.addEventListener("click", () => 
{
        onrampModal?.setAttribute("step", "0");
        }
    )
}
}

private render() {
navigationButtons.innerHTML = `
    <div id="navigation-buttons">
        <button id="back-button" class="navigation-buttons__button-back" >Back</button>
        <button id="next-button" class="navigation-buttons__button--next">next</button>
        <button id="cancel-button" class="navigation-buttons__button--cancel">cancel</button>
    </div>
  `;
}
}
```

Comment: not 100% sure, but most likely your variable "step" is a fixed number, so every time you press the button, its the same number.

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the "step" is not being re-assigned each time you press the button. Maybe try something like this?:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById("back-button")?.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const step = onrampModal?.getAttribute('step');
    onrampModal?.setAttribute("step", (Number(step) - 1).toString());
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clean up your code a bit:

```html
<count-buttons></count-buttons>
<script>
  customElements.define("count-buttons", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const tag = (name,props)=> Object.assign(document.createElement(name),props);
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .append(
          tag("style", {
            innerText: `button{color:green;font-weight:bold}` +
                       `#back{color:red}` +
                       `span{margin:1em;font:21px Arial}`
          }),
          tag("button", {
            id: "back",
            innerText: "Back",
            onclick: (evt) => this.step--
          }),
          this.span = tag("span", {
            innerText: 0
          }),
          tag("button", {
            innerText: "Next",
            onclick: (evt) => this.step++
          }),
        )
    }
    get step() {
        return Number(this.span.innerText);
    }
    set step(value) {
        this.span.innerText = value;
    }
  });
</script>
```